# ROS on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)

Tags: ros, ubuntu-xenial, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is ROS (Indigo or Jade) compatible with Ubuntu 16.04?
If yes, is there some additional steps to install it?
If no, when will it be?

Best,
Jimmy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226098/ros-on-ubuntu-xenial-(16.04)/) by [JimmyB](https://answers.ros.org/users/25886/jimmyb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-02-09

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Supported platforms are documented here: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

Updates for Kinetic are in a PR here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/106 and Kinetic will support Xenial

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run ROS Indigo on Xenial pretty easily with Docker using the following: https://github.com/jbohren/rosdocked

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2016-08-06**:
Can you use the same method to run ROS Jade on Xenial?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-13**:
Well, yes. But you wouldn't really be "running ROS Jade on Xenial". The docker image would be based on Trusty or Utopic or Vivid.